# SOAP HTTP status 500

Tags: java, http, soap, apache-axis

I'm trying to call a SOAP-Service using Axis2.
I generated the javacode using axis2-wsdl2code-maven-plugin.

The Service, I call is programmed in C#.net and the service and server don't provide any logging

My code:

```
FileImageInputStream fis = new FileImageInputStream(new File("C:/projekte/WorkflowPlugins/Cre_IkarosImport/data/import.xml"));
String line = fis.readLine();
StringBuilder fileContent = new StringBuilder();

while(line != null && !line.equals(""))
{
    fileContent.append(line);
    line = fis.readLine();
}

ImportServiceStub importService = new ImportServiceStub("http://win517a007:44102/Import.svc");
importService._getServiceClient().getOptions().setProperty(HTTPConstants.CHUNKED, "false");

importService._getServiceClient().getOptions().setProperty(HTTPConstants.SO_TIMEOUT, 100000);
importService._getServiceClient().getOptions().setProperty(HTTPConstants.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, 100000);
importService._getServiceClient().engageModule("addressing");

DirectImportDocument importDocument = DirectImportDocument.Factory.newInstance();
DirectImportDocument.DirectImport directImport = importDocument.addNewDirectImport();
DirectImportRequest directImportRequest = directImport.addNewRequest();
directImportRequest.setData(fileContent.toString());

importService.directImport(importDocument);
importService._getServiceClient();
```

But everytime, I try to import my file it throws:

```
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The message could not be processed. This is most likely because the action 'http://tempuri.org/IImportService/DirectImport' is incorrect or because the message contains an invalid or expired security context token or because there is a mismatch between bindings. The security context token would be invalid if the service aborted the channel due to inactivity. To prevent the service from aborting idle sessions prematurely increase the Receive timeout on the service endpoint's binding.
at org.apache.axis2.util.Utils.getInboundFaultFromMessageContext(Utils.java:508)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:368)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:414)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:225)
at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:150)
at de.crefo.workflow.ikarosimport.wsdl.ImportServiceStub.directImport(ImportServiceStub.java:988)
at de.crefo.workflow.ikarosimport.actions.IkarosImport.importFile(IkarosImport.java:66)
at de.crefo.workflow.ikarosimport.actions.IkarosImport.main(IkarosImport.java:75)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

Whats caused by an status 500 "Internal Server Error" I found out

It's not a timeout, the exception is thrown instantaneously

Let me know, if you need any further information

Comment: Look in the Server log. There you should see what is happend

Comment: The server does't provide any logging.

Comment: Did you find its solution ? I am also facing same issue.